# fully RFC5321- and 5322-compatible PHP PCRE regex

Tags: php, regex, email, pcre

I'm trying to create a PHP PCRE regex that is (almost) fully compatible with RFC5321 and 5322 to test [email addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address). The only thing I don't require is the (comment) part. I've seen some other attempts at this posted on here, but when I run tests vs. them they don't all work.

I have been working on one that is very close:

```
 ^(([\w \!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~\.]{1,64})|("[\w \!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~\.]{1,64}"))@(([\w\-]*\.?[\w\-]*)|(\[\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\])|(\[IPv6:[\da-fA-F]{0,4}:[\da-fA-F]{0,4}:[\da-fA-F]{0,4}:[\da-fA-F]{0,4}\]))$
```

To break it down:

Local part:

```
(
```

Match at most 64 of the allowed characters

```
   ([\w \!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~\.]{1,64})
    |
```

OR match the same set of characters in a quoted string:

```
   ("[\w \!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~\.]{1,64}")
)
```

end local part.

match @ sign

```
@
```

match domain part:

```
(
```

match domain part using allowed characters:

```
   ([\w\-]*\.?[\w\-]*)
```

or ipv4 (it doesn't check to make sure they are < 255 - that would be handled elsewhere)

```
   (\[\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\])
```

or ipv6

```
   (\[IPv6:[\da-fA-F]{0,4}:[\da-fA-F]{0,4}:[\da-fA-F]{0,4}:[\da-fA-F]{0,4}\])

)
```

The only thing it's missing is the ability to check for multiple consecutive .'s (periods) that are outside a quoted local-part. I ran tests on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) vs. all the addresses below using some of my own tests and the tests on the [wikipedia article about email addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address):

```
bob@smith.com
bob.smith@smith.com
bob-smith@smith.com
bob-smith@bob-smith.com
b0b!-...smith@smith.com <-DOES NOT VALIDATE CORRECTLY - MULTIPLE .'s
bob&smith@smith.com
"bob..smith"@smith.com

simple@example.com
very.common@example.com
disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com
other.email-with-hyphen@example.com
fully-qualified-domain@example.com
user.name+tag+sorting@example.com
x@example.com
example-indeed@strange-example.com
admin@mailserver1
example@s.example
" "@example.org
"john..doe"@example.org

Abc.example.com
A@b@c@example.com
a"b(c)d,e:f;g<h>i[j\k]l@example.com
just"not"right@example.com
this is"not\allowed@example.com
this\ still\"not\\allowed@example.com
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234+x@example.com
john..doe@example.com  <-DOES NOT VALIDATE CORRECTLY - MULTIPLE .'s
john.doe@example..com
```

I attempted to use lookahead and lookbehind assertions to test for the consecutive periods, but I couldn't figure it out. I think that's the only thing it's missing (other than the comments, which for my purposes aren't required).

Is there a way to check for the periods that wouldn't alter what I currently have too much, or would it require a different approach?

Please let me know if I missed anything else.

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `(?!("[^"]*"|[^"])*\.{2})` after `^`. If you test at regex101, use `(?!("[^"\n]*"|[^"\n])*\.{2})`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/R7qRvH/1

Comment: That is perfect, thank you!

Comment: I [posted the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53595241/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `(?!("[^"]*"|[^"])*\.{2})` after `^`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R7qRvH/1).

The `(?!("[^"]*"|[^"])*\.{2})` negative lookahead fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is

- `("[^"]*"|[^"])*` - 0 or more occurrences of a `"` followed with 0+ chars other than `"` and then `"` or any char other than `"`
- `\.{2}` - two consecutive dots.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [read this](http://quetzalcoatal.blogspot.com/2013/12/why-email-is-hard-part-4-email-addresses.html). Suffice it to say that writing a regex that will work 100% is impossible.

I've written a non-Regex implementation [here](https://github.com/jstedfast/EmailValidation). If you port this to php and file an issue on my github page or send me an email (listed on my github page), I will happily link to it.

As you can tell from the [unit tests](https://github.com/jstedfast/EmailValidation/blob/master/UnitTests/Test.cs), it's comprehensive enough to work with EAI addresses as well.

Comment: I figured the reality would likely be more difficult than what I thought it was. I think the hardest part is dealing with the EAI stuff. Thanks for those articles and information!